# Hyper-V could not initialize VM

Tags: windows, virtualization, hyper-v, windows-10

[image]

There are no details in the Event Viewer. All it outputs is:

> 'TEST2' could not initialize. (Virtual machine ID 16C7E436-3199-4D55-BEE2-335685578F99)

What I have tried all resulting in the same issue:

1. Intel Virtualisation (VT-x) is on in the bios. Tried turning it off and on again
2. Hyper V is enabled. Tried disabling it, rebooting. Re-enabling it, rebooting
3. `net localgroup administrators SERVICE /DELETE` (which seems dodgy)
4. Checked Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management is running
5. Restarted Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management
6. Created blank new Virtual Machines with Generation 1 and Generation 2
7. Created blank new Virtual Machines with Virtual Disks on different drives

I have no idea what more to try.

**System Information**

[image]

**Hyper-V Information**

[image]

Comment: Is this a new machine? Has it always done this or was it previously working fine?

Comment: Have you other machines running succesfully?
Are all files in place (configuration files and disk files)?
Have the files been relocated after machine creation?
Is the media where the files for the machine are stored fully available?
Are there sufficient resources available for the machine to run? - Remember that the host needs 4 GB memory for itself. If there are 7 GB left on the system and the guest requires (is configured with) 4 GB - it will not start.

Comment: Steps 1 and 2 were kind of pointless as you wouldn't have been able to install the Hyper-V role nor create virtual machines if those items weren't already true. As for steps 6 and 7 I'm assuming that you meant to say that you got the same result from both, which is that you got the same error?

Comment: NO machines work. New or existing VM's all break.
@joeqwerty well I was just trying everything... I get many attempts may seem redundant. Same error for every thing tried.

Comment: @MikaelDyreborgHansen no machines work. new or existing.

Comment: Check if you can find a more specific error message in the Hyper-V event logs, they are in the Event Viewer, under "Applications and Services Logs" -> "Microsoft" -> "Windows" and Hyper-V*...

Comment: The errors in the Event View give no information just the same ''TEST2' could not initialize. (Virtual machine ID 16C7E436-3199-4D55-BEE2-335685578F99)' error. Nothing else.

Comment: Is the "Execute Disable (XD)" Enabled in the BIOS? And check if the BIOS is up to date

Answer (score -1):

Uninstalling the Remote Server Admin Tools solved it for me. Give that a shot.

Comment: Sad that this was downvoted without a reason..